# Prevent loops in many-to-many self-referencing relationship (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many

Suppose you want to have a hierarchy of `thing`s where a `thing` can have multiple `thing` parents and children:

```sql
CREATE TABLE thing (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE thing_association (
    parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    child_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (parent_id, child_id),
    CHECK (parent_id != child_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES thing(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES thing(id)
);
```

The `CHECK` constraint prevents a `thing` from having a relationship with itself, and the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint prevents duplicate relationships, but can loops be prevented?

More precisely, if row `(x, y)` exists in the `thing_association` table, can the row `(y, x)` be prevented from being inserted?

Going a step further, if rows `(x, y)` and `(y, z)` exist in the `thing_association`, can the row `(z, x)` be prevented from being inserted?

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402048/postgresql-reverse-foreign-key-constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was hoping to accomplish this without triggers, but I'm not sure that's possible. I was able to accomplish this with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger:

```sql
CREATE TABLE thing (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE thing_association (
    parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    child_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (parent_id, child_id),
    CHECK (parent_id != child_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES thing(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES thing(id)
);

/* maps every thing to all of it's parents */
CREATE VIEW thing_hierarchy AS
WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
    SELECT
        child_id,
        parent_id
    FROM thing_association
    UNION SELECT
        children.child_id,
        parents.parent_id
    FROM thing_association AS parents
    INNER JOIN children
        ON children.parent_id = parents.child_id
) SELECT * FROM children;

CREATE FUNCTION check_thing_association_loop() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF ((NEW.parent_id, NEW.child_id) in (SELECT child_id, parent_id FROM thing_hierarchy)) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannont create a hierarchy loop';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER thing_association_insert_check
    BEFORE INSERT ON thing_association
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION check_thing_association_loop();
```

You could merge the view into the trigger function, but the view is useful on its own and it keeps things succint.